# Return Array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, return

I cant return array in c,i am quite new to C so i probably do some kind of funny mistake, here is
the code:

```
#define MAXSIZE 100
int recievedNumbers[MAXSIZE];
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  recievedNumbers = getACOfNumber(256);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(recievedNumbers) / 8; i++) {
    Serial.print(recievedNumbers[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

int* getACOfNumber(int theNumber) {
  bool done = false;
  int i = 0;
  int theArray[100];
  while (!done) {
    if (theNumber % 2 == 0) {
      theNumber = theNumber / 2;
      theArray[i] = 2;
    } else if (theNumber % 3 == 0) {
      theNumber = theNumber / 3;
      theArray[i] = 3;
    }
    else if (theNumber % 5 == 0) {
      theNumber = theNumber / 5;
      theArray[i] = 5;
    }
    else if (theNumber % 7 == 0) {
      theNumber = theNumber / 7;
      theArray[i] = 7;
    } else {
      theArray[i] = theNumber;
      done = true;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return theArray;
}
```

Error Message :

> AC:10: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int
>   [100]'
>
> exit status 1 incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int
>   [100]'

Comment: It's not a "funny mistake", but a serious one. You are trying to return a *locally* allocated object. Once the function returns, there is no more `theArray` exist.

Comment: Fyi, `theArray` doesn't exist anymore once your function returns, so returning its address is pointless, You need a static, a global, dynamic allocation, or a caller-provided buffer. Choose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not assign to an array from an expression:

```
int recievedNumbers[MAXSIZE];
...
recievedNumbers = getACOfNumber(256);
```

Instead:

```
memcpy(receivedNumbers, getACOfNumber(256), sizeof(receivedNumbers));
```

An notice that you are using a local array whose lifetime ends with the function, change to

```
static int theArray[100];
```

or better yet

```
int *theArray = calloc(100, sizeof(*theArray)); /* Zero initializes the array */
```

don't forget to call `free` at the end:

```
int *temp = getACOfNumber(256);

memcpy(receivedNumbers, temp, sizeof(receivedNumbers));
free(temp);
```

But why don't you pass the original array to the function?:

```
getACOfNumber(receivedNumbers);
...
void getACOfNumber(int *theArray) {
```

Comment: The `static` approach will work only if this function called once, and it is not expected it to return more than one different objects..

Comment: Thank you really much for the solution.But i am not 100% sure what is "sizeof".

Comment: `sizeof` gets the size of any object or primitive type

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `int theArray[100]` with `int *theArray=malloc(100*sizeof int)`.

While internally in C <del>arrays are pointers</del> arrays and pointers look very similar, they are of different type - this is what compiler is complaining about.
Additionally, the compiler has saved you from a painful memory corruption error:

when you define a local array variable inside your function, it gets memory allocated on function's stack. This gets released when function ends, so your result either becomes invalid or may become invalid later, or worse, cause various segmentation faults. `malloc` allocates memory in global application heap, it won't go bad after function terminates. But then, don't forget to `free` it after use.

Comment: *While internally in C arrays are pointers,* - this is going to get you into troubles

Comment: This is reasonable advice and analysis, except that C arrays are not at all the same thing as pointers.  It does not, however, address the compiler diagnostic about which the OP inquired.

Comment: Fixed to remove ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can't return an array from any function, but you don't need to do so too. Because you can pass the array to the funtion (the array's reference will be sent) and change whatever you want in the array. The change(s) will stay in the array even if the program comes out of that function. Thank you.

Comment: Actually,i know that.But you can see the other answers.You can return the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining about the line

```
recievedNumbers = getACOfNumber(256);
```

You cannot use the `=` operator to assign the contents of an array; an array expression may not be the target of an assignment operation.  Also, the result of `getACOfNumber` is an `int *`, which is not the same type as `int [100]`.

This *could* work if you declared `receivedNumbers` as

```
int *recievedNumbers;
```

In that case you're assigning a pointer to a pointer, which should work.

But, you have another problem:

```
int* getACOfNumber(int theNumber) {
  bool done = false;
  int i = 0;
  int theArray[100];
  ...
  return theArray;
}
```

This will not do what you expect.  Once the `getACOfNumber` function exits, `theArray` *no longer exists* - the pointer you return is no longer *valid*.

IMO, your best bet is to pass the array as a parameter to `getACOfNumber` and update it directly in the function:

```
getACOfNumber( 256, receivedNumbers, MAXSIZE );
...
void getACOfNumber( int number, int *theArray, size_t max )
{
  bool done = false;
  size_t i = 0;
  while ( i < max && !done )
  {
    ... // use existing code
  }
}
```